# Some text is barely showing in answers in the tour due to MathJax formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

<s><kbd>[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOidM.png)</kbd></s>

<kbd>[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfnMB.png)</kbd>

I would suggest the last line is removed, or the `max-height` expanded to 190px. This would allow the gradient to take effect.

<kbd>[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y7C5.png)</kbd>

---

This cutoff was due to window sizes - my window was 960px, not the required 1000px. However, at full size, the line is slightly visible - it looks a little odd:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Simply adding 10px to the max height makes this more paletable:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Never seen this on the main site in desktop version. Are these from mobile?

Comment: @IͶΔ No, Chrome 49.0.2623.108 on Ubuntu 64 Bit

Comment: Could you give me the link to the post in question?

Comment: @IͶΔ It's the tour. It appears to be an issue with screen size - I'd resized my window to be less than 1000px.

Comment: Oh crap someone reads tour!!!!one!

Comment: repro'ed. Also bad [comment choice](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XqlUy.png).

Comment: comment rem'd: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30870/what-is-the-molecularity-of-a-reversible-reaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was about to change the question used for the [tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) I noticed it was already exchanged. It now uses a less MathJax loaded question and the gradient should now work properly.